# how to use session to avoid some user to view some pages?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Thank You very much for answer my question, because i am very new in asp.net, I am really appreciated

I have a Session to identity the user in the controller

```
    Session["UserId"] = UserNo;
    Session["UserType"] = UserType;
```

What can i do to avoid the User such as the Session["UserType"] is "3" and then avoid him/her to login to some web pages?

I need to control that in the controller, view of filter config?

Comment: Just redirect them after checking with `if` condition in controller action method, e.g. `if (Session["UserId"] == 3) { return RedirectToAction([forbidden page URL here]); }`

Comment: thank you @TetsuyaYamamoto, i don't know it the answer is so simple

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a `BaseController` and all the other controllers that you want to check User, should inherit it. Before a `ActionResult` requested, first the `BaseController`'s constructor will work, so at constructor of `BaseController` you can do this,

```
public BaseController()
        {
            try
            {
                int UserID = 0;
                if (System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Session["UserId"] != null)
                    UserID = Convert.ToInt32(System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Session["UserId"]);

                if (!(UserID > 0))
                {
                    System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Response.Redirect("controller/view");
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                throw ex;
            }
        }
```

Hope helps,

Comment: Except that maybe instead of putting this logic in the construction, use an [`OnActionExecuting` override](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.controller.onactionexecuting(v=vs.118).aspx)

Comment: i did a try catch method, and the return won't works ...            
when i debug it, it goes to the "return RedirectToAction ... " but didn't routed to the following url

catch  {
                return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
            }

Comment: Use `System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Response.Redirect("controller/view"); `method is not `ActionResult`, you can't use `RedirectToAction`. @KeonVong

Comment: i don't know it i need to return or not , because it is a "public ActionResult " method, may need to have return value?

Comment: Forexample there is IndexController that derived from BaseController and there is an `ActionResult` called `Login`, Before `Login` works, BaseController's Constructor will work. Use the exact solution. @KeonVong

Answer (score 1):

Simply you have redirect the user if

```
public ActionResult Method()
 {
  if( Session["UserType"] = 3)
   {
     return View([forbidden page URL here]);
   }
  else
   {
     return View("controller/view");
   } 
 }
```

Hope it Helps.

Comment: `if( Session["UserType"] = 3)` I think you need to modify this line.

Comment: Oops Thanks @MAdeelKhalid I did modify it

Comment: i did a try catch method, and the return won't works ...            
when i debug it, it goes to the "return RedirectToAction ... " but didn't routed to the following url

catch  {
                return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
            }

Comment: what is the exception?

Answer (score 1):

You just need to check your sessions value everytime a user tries to access a certain page.

EDIT:
Try this

```
public ActionResult Details(int id)
{
    var details = context.checkIfUserExist(userID);
    if (details == null)
    {
        return RedirectToAction("takeHimSomewhere");
    }
    return View(details);
}
```

Comment: i did a try catch method, and the return won't works ...            
when i debug it, it goes to the "return RedirectToAction ... " but didn't routed to the following url

catch  {
                return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
            }

Comment: I advice not to use Response.Redirect on MVC. [Performance issues].

Answer (score 1):

While all other answers are right and working, i would like to lead you to the  more 'asp-ish' style of solving this problem, which also reduces your code because you do not have to write a if else in every of your controller.

In ASP.NET there is a Identity Concept which does exactly what you want to archive by hand. 
Have a look here: https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/aspnet/core/security/authentication/identity

Once you implemented the Identity, you can just mark your controller methods with [Authorize].

https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/aspnet/core/security/authorization/introduction